# Debug cgi application on asp web page?

Tags: c++, asp.net, cgi, exe

We have a c++ cgi application that we normally host on a server for everyone to access.  I am trying to get this exe in some sort of order to debug through, which I don't know is possible to debug the exe on a server?(remote debugging like in Eclipse??)  Is it possible to create an asp web page and have that page host this exe file so that I can debug directly from within visual studio?